# Unreadable Firebase Crash Reports

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-crash-reporting

I followed the Firebase Crash Reporting Youtube video and implemented all the steps -  generating Private Key and storing this in Key Folder.

```
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:XXXXXXX:ios:xxxxxxx

"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${PROJECT_DIR}/Keys/XXXXXXXXXX.json"
```

I tested the app using the

```
fatalError()
```

It showed the correct error and where it was located using the simulator.

My trouble is that now that my app is live, the Firebase Crash Reporting Stack trace is Unreadable.

```
1 APP NAME XXXXXXXXXX + XXXXXX
2 APP NAME XXXXXXXXXX + XXXXXX
3 APP NAME XXXXXXXXXX + XXXXXX
```

For each crash, there is a way to upload symbol file.  I don't know where to put this...

*Upload symbol file to symbolicate future stack traces for UUID XXXXXXXXXX*

```
./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload <service-account-file> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Can anyone give me some advice on where to look at please?